# why the inner product with an element that does not belong to a convex cone is negative

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-cone, dual-cone

Let us consider a set with an infinite number of vectors $\{v_k \mid k \in \mathbb{N} \}$ with $n$ cordinates, and if we consider the conned convex set containing all theses vectors, denoted by $K$.

My question is why if we take $a$ non zero vector, that does not belong to $K$, then we get that
$$\langle a,v_k \rangle \leq 0,$$
for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site :) I suspect that there are some assumptions missing in your question that would make the statement true, e.g. what vector space are we working in, does the sequence of vectors converge, what is your definition of the cone, etc. Please include these. Also, whether this is homework or not, it is always nice to include some of your own work. Finally, maybe including the source/reference where you got this question from is very appreciated.

Comment: What is a conned convex set?